# Как максимально точно настроить устройство в Android Emulator, чтобы отображение соответствовало реальному устройству

Tags: android-studio, мобильная-разработка, android

Добрый день. Никак не могу настроить виртуальное устройство в Android Emulator Android Studio так, чтобы оно максимально соответствовало по параметрам экрана реального устройства для которого я пишу приложение, и на котором время от времени я все тестирую. На руках у меня есть планшет Softwinner Q88H Android 4.4.2, DPI 140, 6.9 inches, 538x1024px.
Скрин 2.
Добавляю в Android Studio устройство с такими же характеристиками, но на выходе получаю расхождение в отображении элементов Activity.
Так на реальном:
Скрин 1.
А вот так на виртуальном:
Скрин 3.
Ни как не могу понять в чем дело. Вообще возможно ли добиться полного соответствия? И как на виртуальном устройстве панель навигации разместить внизу экрана, как на реальном устройстве, а не справа? Спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.
Настройки эмулятора:
`

```
hw.cpu.arch = x86
hw.cpu.model = qemu32
hw.cpu.ncore = 2
hw.ramSize = 512
hw.screen = multi-touch
hw.mainKeys = false
hw.trackBall = false
hw.keyboard = true
hw.keyboard.lid = false
hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
hw.dPad = false
hw.gsmModem = true
hw.sdCard.path = E:\Softwinner_Q88H_API_19_2.avd\sdcard.img
disk.cachePartition = true
disk.cachePartition.path = E:\Softwinner_Q88H_API_19_2.avd/cache.img
disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
hw.lcd.width = 1024
hw.lcd.height = 538
hw.lcd.depth = 16
hw.lcd.density = 160
hw.lcd.backlight = true
hw.gpu.enabled = true
hw.gpu.mode = host
hw.gpu.blacklisted = no
hw.initialOrientation = landscape
vm.heapSize = 64
hw.useext4 = true
kernel.path = E:\Android\SDK/system-images\android-19\google_apis\x86\/kernel-ranchu
kernel.newDeviceNaming = yes
kernel.supportsYaffs2 = yes
disk.ramdisk.path = E:\Android\SDK/system-images\android-19\google_apis\x86\/ramdisk.img
disk.systemPartition.initPath = E:\Android\SDK/system-images\android-19\google_apis\x86\/system.img
disk.systemPartition.size = 550m
disk.dataPartition.path = E:\Softwinner_Q88H_API_19_2.avd/userdata-qemu.img
disk.dataPartition.size = 800m
avd.name = Softwinner_Q88H_API_19_2
```

`

Comment: Настройки эмулятора в студию.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос настройками. Пробовал менять параметр hw.lcd.density = 160 на значение 140, но после этого эмулятор не запускается вообще. А через мастер создания устройства этот параметр негде ввести.